# TableView - Mysql Swift

Tags: mysql, swift

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне использовать данные с базы данных в tableview?

Я только учусь по этому прошу помощи

Вот что у меня имеется

> Данные которые получает MessageTableViewCell.swift
>
> {
>       id = 13;
>       "id_from" = 1;
>       "id_to" = 1;
>       message = 123; }
>
> Переменная которая содержит массив с данным выглядит вот так
>
> let jsonArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("JSON")
>
> ```
>     Optional({
>      id = 13;
>      "id_from" = 1;
>      "id_to" = 1;
>      message = 123; })
> ```

Код: MessageTableViewCell.swift

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/getmessage.php")
        let id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("ID") as? String
        let idmy = id as! String!

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let posting = "id=\(idmy)"
        print(posting)
        request.HTTPBody = posting.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }


            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {
                    var JsonMessageArray = parseJSON
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(JsonMessageArray, forKey: "JSON")
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }


        }

        task.resume()
```

Код: MessageViewController.swift

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewMessage: UITableView!

    let jsonArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("JSON")

    private let userNameFrom = ["Alex Alexeev","Oly Mastova","Nasty Vetrova","Vera Stohina","Oksana Sizova"]
    private let messageText = ["Привет","Как дела?","Ты где?","Мы ждем","Я работаю"]
    private let timeMessageFrom = ["1 мин. назад","14:45","23:20","Вчера","1 февраля"]
    private let messageAvatarUser = ["374.png","374.png","374.png","374.png","374.png"]
    private let idUserFrom = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.

        return userNameFrom.count
        return messageText.count
        return idUserFrom.count
        return timeMessageFrom.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "Message"

        let cellMessage = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MessageTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...


        cellMessage.useravaImageView.image = UIImage(named: messageAvatarUser[indexPath.row])
        cellMessage.usermessageTextLabel.text = messageText[indexPath.row]
        cellMessage.timemessageTextLabel.text = timeMessageFrom[indexPath.row]
        cellMessage.usernameTextLabel.text = userNameFrom[indexPath.row]
        cellMessage.idTextLabelUser.text = idUserFrom[indexPath.row]

        return cellMessage
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedCellMsg = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        //let selectMSG = selectedCellMsg!.textLabel!.text
        let selectMSG = idUserFrom[indexPath.row]
        let selectAvaFromMsg = UIImage(named: messageAvatarUser[indexPath.row])

        if selectedCellMsg != nil {
            let selectNameFromMsg = userNameFrom[indexPath.row]
            let idUserFromSelect = idUserFrom[indexPath.row]

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(selectNameFromMsg, forKey: "selectMsgNameUser")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(idUserFromSelect, forKey: "idUserTo")


        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessageWindow") as! MessageWindowViewController
        self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

        }
        print(selectMSG)

    }
```

Comment: Начнем, собственно, с того, что здесь работа с JSON, а не MySQL. `{ id = 13; "id_from" = 1; "id_to" = 1; message = 123; }` неверный JSON. Дальше - больше.

Comment: данные то с mysql в формате json) но как их использовать я не понимаю в table view

Comment: {"id":13,"id_from":1,"id_to":1,"message":123} Вот это json, а у вас что-то невалидное.

Comment: так а в чем вопрос то?

Comment: вопрос в том как использовать json данные в table view

Comment: Переведите JSON в какой-нибудь Dictionary, и используйте как хотите

Comment: а зачем весь этот код в вопросе? я так понимаю, что верхний блок кода получает json с сервера и сохраняет в userDefaults. Там что то не работает? если да, то что, если нет, то не надо это вообще в вопросе писать. дальше в нижнем блоке кода, вы записываете свой json в переменную `jsonArray`. если после этого сделать priint, там все оно будет? Допустим да, тогда что надо конкретно сделать с этим json? например, записать id в text. Скажите конкретно. Далее у вас в методе `numberOfRowsInSection` 4 return один за одним - выполнится только первый.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ваши комментарии которые были не по теме!
Вопрос решил сам!

Comment: @Malyshev пожалуйста, опубликуйте найденное решение в виде ответа. Оно будет полезно будущим читателям.